# Redis cascading replication

Tags: database, redis, replication

I have cascading replication on redis

```
A -> B -> C
```

When I insert data on A, then I can get it on B and C
If I insert data into the B, then I cannot receive it on the lower slave C.

The documentation has the following:

```
Replicas are able to accept connections from other replicas.
Aside from connecting a number of replicas to the same master,
replicas can also be connected to other replicas in a cascading-like
structure. Since Redis 4.0, all the sub-replicas will receive
exactly the same replication stream from the master.
```

Can I configure replication to write A/B and read from C?

Answer (score 3):

Probably will not be able to configure such replication.
read the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/replication), found such an item

```
Also note that since Redis 4.0 replica writes are only local, and are not propagated to sub-replicas attached to the instance. Sub-replicas instead will always receive the replication stream identical to the one sent by the top-level master to the intermediate replicas. So for example in the following setup:

A ---> B ---> C

Even if B is writable, C will not see B writes and will instead have identical dataset as the master instance A.
```